# Classic ASP download file from sql server database return 0 byte

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, download, adodb

I'm having problems when I download files bigger than 5mb (until 10mb this is the limit by me).

I just got a 0 byte file. It's like the file is empty, BTW, the file is uploaded correctly on the db. Checked that using the tsql datalength()

This is my code:

```
    <%
Response.Buffer = false
ssql = "select name, filestore from files where id=" & request("idfile")
                    Set oRs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
                    oRs.Open ssql, Application("myConn")



    If Not ors.EOF Then
             Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "filename=""" & ors("Name") & """"

                Response.ContentType = "application/unknown"
        Response.BinaryWrite oRs("filestore")
        Response.end
      End If


      ors.Close
      Set ors = nothing %>
```

Any Idea???

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989334/how-do-i-enable-upload-of-large-files-in-classic-asp-on-iis-7

Comment: This might help too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21740443/classic-asp-iis-6-response-buffer-limit-exceeded/21748715

Comment: @Andrew Your comment linked to a post about increasing the upload (request) limit for Classic ASP. The OP is writing a page to allow users to download from a page and stream the file out of a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answers guys.  I finally found the problem. It was on IIS related to the asp buffer limit. Increasing that setting worked fine.

Comment: Thats one approach the more sensible one however is to use the `ADODB.Stream` object to stream the data put in meaningful chunks that never max out the Response Buffer Limit.